# MonacaでCordova5.2にアップデートしたらAndroidビルドに失敗してしまいます

Tags: android, monaca, cordova

MonacaでCordova4.1からCordova5.2にアップデートしたところ、Androidビルドに失敗するようになりました。
ビルド設定などの対応方法があれば、お教えください。

・Cordovaアップデート前はビルドに成功していました。
　・ビルドではなくMonacaデバッガーで動作させた場合、特にエラーはなく動作します。
　・デバックビルド、リリースビルド両方ともビルドに失敗します。
　・iOSビルドの場合、問題なくビルドに成功します。

ビルド失敗後のメッセージには、ビルド設定に間違いがある可能性があるので下記の設定を再確認してください
と表示されます。
　・AndroidManifest.xmlは正しく設定されていますか？
　・キーストアの設定が正しいですか？
→これらの設定はCordovaアップデート前から変更していません。

以下はビルド失敗時のログになります。

```
Temporary folder: /private/tmp/monaca/565bfce4fd1734416071b4f9
Downloading project
Download complete
Running for 5.2
plugin add mobi.monaca.plugins.Monaca
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf enabled
Installing &quot;mobi.monaca.plugins.Monaca&quot; for android
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf disabled
plugin add cordova-plugin-camera@0.3.4
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf enabled
Fetching plugin &quot;cordova-plugin-camera@0.3.4&quot; via npm
Installing &quot;org.apache.cordova.camera&quot; for android
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf disabled
plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer@0.4.8
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf enabled
Fetching plugin &quot;cordova-plugin-file-transfer@0.4.8&quot; via npm
Installing &quot;org.apache.cordova.file-transfer&quot; for android
Fetching plugin &quot;org.apache.cordova.file&quot; via npm
WARNING: org.apache.cordova.file has been renamed to cordova-plugin-file. You may not be getting the latest version! We suggest you `cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.file` and `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file`.
Fetching plugin &quot;org.apache.cordova.file&quot; via cordova plugins registry
Installing &quot;org.apache.cordova.file&quot; for android
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf disabled
plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen@0.3.5
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf enabled
Fetching plugin &quot;cordova-plugin-splashscreen@0.3.5&quot; via npm
Installing &quot;org.apache.cordova.splashscreen&quot; for android
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf disabled
plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar@0.1.9
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf enabled
Fetching plugin &quot;cordova-plugin-statusbar@0.1.9&quot; via npm
Installing &quot;org.apache.cordova.statusbar&quot; for android
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf disabled
plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.0.0
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf enabled
Fetching plugin &quot;cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.0.0&quot; via npm
Installing &quot;cordova-plugin-whitelist&quot; for android
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf disabled
plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview@1.3.1 --variable XWALK_VERSION=14.43.343.25 
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf enabled
Fetching plugin &quot;cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview@1.3.1&quot; via npm
Installing &quot;cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview&quot; for android
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf disabled
Project has 7 plugins.
8 plugins has been installed.
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf enabled
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf disabled
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf enabled
Running command: /private/tmp/monaca/565bfce4fd1734416071b4f9/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/build --debug
ANDROID_HOME=/Applications/android-sdk-macosx
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home
Running: /private/tmp/monaca/565bfce4fd1734416071b4f9/android/skeleton/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /private/tmp/monaca/565bfce4fd1734416071b4f9/android/skeleton/platforms/android/build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
embedded
WARNING [Project: :] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
WARNING [Project: :] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
WARNING [Project: :] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
WARNING [Project: :] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:14.43.343.25
:preBuild
:compileArmv7DebugNdk
:preArmv7DebugBuild
:checkArmv7DebugManifest
:preX86DebugBuild
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles
:CordovaLib:preBuild
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJava
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugJar
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk
:CordovaLib:packageDebugJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary
:preArmv7ReleaseBuild
:preX86ReleaseBuild
:CordovaLib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles
:CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild
:CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareReleaseDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources
:CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest
:CordovaLib:processReleaseResources
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseJava
:CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseJar
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleRelease
:prepareOrgXwalkXwalk_core_library144334325Library
:prepareArmv7DebugDependencies
:compileArmv7DebugAidl
:compileArmv7DebugRenderscript
:generateArmv7DebugBuildConfig
:generateArmv7DebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeArmv7DebugAssets
:createXwalkCommandLineFileArmv7Debug
:generateArmv7DebugResValues
:generateArmv7DebugResources
ERROR: 9-patch image /private/tmp/monaca/565bfce4fd1734416071b4f9/android/skeleton/platforms/android/res/drawable-port-xhdpi/screen.9.png malformed.
       Must have one-pixel frame that is either transparent or white.
:mergeArmv7DebugResources
Error: Failed to run command:
    /Applications/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt s -i /private/tmp/monaca/565bfce4fd1734416071b4f9/android/skeleton/platforms/android/res/drawable-port-xhdpi/screen.9.png -o /private/tmp/monaca/565bfce4fd1734416071b4f9/android/skeleton/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/armv7/debug/drawable-port-xhdpi-v4/screen.9.png
Error Code:
    42
Output:
    ERROR: 9-patch image /private/tmp/monaca/565bfce4fd1734416071b4f9/android/skeleton/platforms/android/res/drawable-port-xhdpi/screen.9.png malformed.
           Must have one-pixel frame that is either transparent or white.

:mergeArmv7DebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task &apos;:mergeArmv7DebugResources&apos;.
&gt; Error: Failed to run command:
    /Applications/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt s -i /private/tmp/monaca/565bfce4fd1734416071b4f9/android/skeleton/platforms/android/res/drawable-port-xhdpi/screen.9.png -o /private/tmp/monaca/565bfce4fd1734416071b4f9/android/skeleton/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/armv7/debug/drawable-port-xhdpi-v4/screen.9.png
  Error Code:
    42
  Output:
    ERROR: 9-patch image /private/tmp/monaca/565bfce4fd1734416071b4f9/android/skeleton/platforms/android/res/drawable-port-xhdpi/screen.9.png malformed.
           Must have one-pixel frame that is either transparent or white.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.967 secs

/private/tmp/monaca/565bfce4fd1734416071b4f9/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: /private/tmp/monaca/565bfce4fd1734416071b4f9/android/skeleton/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/private/tmp/monaca/565bfce4fd1734416071b4f9/android/skeleton/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /private/tmp/monaca/565bfce4fd1734416071b4f9/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /private/tmp/monaca/565bfce4fd1734416071b4f9/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/data/monaca_build_module/5.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:822:5)
Build error: Error building project source code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errorが書いてある場所はここですね

```
ERROR: 9-patch image /private/tmp/monaca/565bfce4fd1734416071b4f9/android/skeleton/platforms/android/res/drawable-port-xhdpi/screen.9.png malformed.
       Must have one-pixel frame that is either transparent or white.
:mergeArmv7DebugResources
Error: Failed to run command:
    /Applications/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt s -i /private/tmp/monaca/565bfce4fd1734416071b4f9/android/skeleton/platforms/android/res/drawable-port-xhdpi/screen.9.png -o /private/tmp/monaca/565bfce4fd1734416071b4f9/android/skeleton/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/armv7/debug/drawable-port-xhdpi-v4/screen.9.png
```

`drawable-port-xhdpi`のスプラッシュ画像が原因ですかね？
`9-patch`の画像を`9-patch`だと認識できていないみたいなので、
真黒の黒塗りで良いのでpngの仮画像をアップロードしてビルドしてみてください。
もしビルドできるようであれば、アイコン・スプラッシュ画像が原因です。

その場合、もう一度上げなおす必要がありそうですね。

Comment: アイコンとスプラッシュ画像を登録しなおしてみたらビルドが成功しました。  
既存プロジェクトをCordova5.2にアップデートした際に、これらの設定が  
うまく引継がれない場合があるのかもしれません。