# Androidのビルドで失敗する

Tags: android, monaca

ビルドが通ってapkファイルが出力できていたのですが、アイコンを設定したところビルドに失敗します。
エラー内容は以下です。

正直なとろこ、エラー文を見ても？？？と言った状態です。

```
Temporary folder: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23
Downloading project
Download complete
Running for 4.1
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf enabled
Installing &quot;mobi.monaca.plugins.Monaca&quot; for android
cordova version not detected (lacks script &quot;/private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/version&quot; ), continuing.
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf disabled
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf enabled
Installing &quot;org.apache.cordova.splashscreen&quot; for android
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf disabled
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf enabled
Installing &quot;org.apache.cordova.vibration&quot; for android
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf disabled
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf enabled
Installing &quot;mobi.monaca.plugins.WebIntent&quot; for android
cordova version not detected (lacks script &quot;/private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/version&quot; ), continuing.
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf disabled
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf enabled
Running command: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/hooks/after_prepare/monaca_enterprise_encrypt.js /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf disabled
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf enabled
Running command: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/build --release
Buildfile: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-release-mode:

-release-obfuscation-check:
     [echo] proguard.config is ${proguard.config}

-pre-build:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 23.0.2
 [checkenv] Installed at /Applications/adt-bundle-mac/sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: MainActivity
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 20.0.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for MainActivity...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/libs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/ant-build
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/ant-build/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/ant-build/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/ant-build/rsLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/ant-gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/ant-build/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/ant-build/dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for MainActivity...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with &apos;release&apos;...

nodeps:

-set-mode-check:

-set-release-mode:

-release-obfuscation-check:
     [echo] proguard.config is ${proguard.config}

-pre-build:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 23.0.2
 [checkenv] Installed at /Applications/adt-bundle-mac/sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: MainActivity
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 20.0.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for MainActivity...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/libs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/rsLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for MainActivity...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 93 source files to /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
     [echo] Creating library output jar file...
      [jar] Building jar: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
     [echo] Library project: do not convert bytecode...

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/res
   [crunch] To destination dir: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [echo] Library project: do not package resources...

-package:
     [echo] Library project: do not package apk...

-post-package:

-release-prompt-for-password:

-release-nosign:
     [echo] 
[propertyfile] Creating new property file: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop

-release-sign:

-post-build:

release:

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [aapt] res/drawable-hdpi/screen.png:0: error: Resource entry screen is already defined.
     [aapt] res/drawable-hdpi/screen.9.png:0: Originally defined here.
     [aapt] res/drawable-ldpi/screen.png:0: error: Resource entry screen is already defined.
     [aapt] res/drawable-ldpi/screen.9.png:0: Originally defined here.
     [aapt] res/drawable-mdpi/screen.png:0: error: Resource entry screen is already defined.
     [aapt] res/drawable-mdpi/screen.9.png:0: Originally defined here.
     [aapt] res/drawable-xhdpi/screen.png:0: error: Resource entry screen is already defined.
     [aapt] res/drawable-xhdpi/screen.9.png:0: Originally defined here.
     [aapt] res/drawable-xxhdpi/screen.png:0: error: Resource entry screen is already defined.
     [aapt] res/drawable-xxhdpi/screen.9.png:0: Originally defined here.
     [aapt] res/drawable-xxxhdpi/screen.png:0: error: Resource entry screen is already defined.
     [aapt] res/drawable-xxxhdpi/screen.9.png:0: Originally defined here.
     [aapt] res/drawable-land-hdpi/screen.png:0: error: Resource entry screen is already defined.
     [aapt] res/drawable-land-hdpi/screen.9.png:0: Originally defined here.
     [aapt] res/drawable-land-ldpi/screen.png:0: error: Resource entry screen is already defined.
     [aapt] res/drawable-land-ldpi/screen.9.png:0: Originally defined here.
     [aapt] res/drawable-land-mdpi/screen.png:0: error: Resource entry screen is already defined.
     [aapt] res/drawable-land-mdpi/screen.9.png:0: Originally defined here.
     [aapt] res/drawable-land-xhdpi/screen.png:0: error: Resource entry screen is already defined.
     [aapt] res/drawable-land-xhdpi/screen.9.png:0: Originally defined here.
     [aapt] res/drawable-land-xxhdpi/screen.png:0: error: Resource entry screen is already defined.
     [aapt] res/drawable-land-xxhdpi/screen.9.png:0: Originally defined here.
     [aapt] res/drawable-land-xxxhdpi/screen.png:0: error: Resource entry screen is already defined.
     [aapt] res/drawable-land-xxxhdpi/screen.9.png:0: Originally defined here.
     [aapt] res/drawable-port-hdpi/screen.png:0: error: Resource entry screen is already defined.
     [aapt] res/drawable-port-hdpi/screen.9.png:0: Originally defined here.
     [aapt] res/drawable-port-ldpi/screen.png:0: error: Resource entry screen is already defined.
     [aapt] res/drawable-port-ldpi/screen.9.png:0: Originally defined here.
     [aapt] res/drawable-port-mdpi/screen.png:0: error: Resource entry screen is already defined.
     [aapt] res/drawable-port-mdpi/screen.9.png:0: Originally defined here.
     [aapt] res/drawable-port-xhdpi/screen.png:0: error: Resource entry screen is already defined.
     [aapt] res/drawable-port-xhdpi/screen.9.png:0: Originally defined here.
     [aapt] res/drawable-port-xxhdpi/screen.png:0: error: Resource entry screen is already defined.
     [aapt] res/drawable-port-xxhdpi/screen.9.png:0: Originally defined here.
     [aapt] res/drawable-port-xxxhdpi/screen.png:0: error: Resource entry screen is already defined.
     [aapt] res/drawable-port-xxxhdpi/screen.9.png:0: Originally defined here.

BUILD FAILED
/Applications/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:653: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Applications/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:698: null returned: 1

Total time: 4 seconds

/private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: ant with args: release,-f,/private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: /private/tmp/monaca/568cc6a77e21933111a53a23/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:822:5)
Build error: Error building project source code
```

Comment: 英語のStackOverflowに同じような質問と回答がありますが、どうですか？ http://stackoverflow.com/a/27738942/3741336

Answer (score 1):

解決かと言われると微妙ですが、9.pngでスプラッシュ画像を作成すると問題なくビルドできました。

ただ、通常のpng画像でもビルドは可能だと思っているので、よくわからないです。

Comment: 似たような質問（ http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/19470 ）があったのですが同じ原因だったりするんでしょうか？プロジェクトのアップデートでMonacaが何をしているのか分からないのでなんとも言えないですが