# Monacaで以前リリースビルドできていたAndroidアプリがビルドできなくなった

Tags: monaca

こちらの質問に似ていますが、やや状況が違いますので、新たに質問させていただきます。
[MonacaでCordova5.2にアップデートしたらAndroidビルドに失敗してしまいます](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/19470/monaca%E3%81%A7cordova5-2%E3%81%AB%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89android%E3%83%93%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89%E3%81%AB%E5%A4%B1%E6%95%97%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99)

2016年3月頃にリリースビルドできたファイルをインポートし、一切の変更を加えず、再度ビルドしようとしたところ、以下のような文言のエラーが返され、ビルドできませんでした。

一度正しくビルドできたものを、全く変更せず、手順も同じようにリリースビルドをしようとした際、ビルドできなくなることなど、あるのでしょうか。あった場合、どのような原因で、どう対応すれば良いでしょうか。

お教えいただければ幸いです。

> **ビルドに失敗しました**
>   アプリのビルドに失敗しました。ビルド設定に間違いがある可能性があります。下記の設定を再確認してください。
>   ・AndroidManifest.xmlは正しく記述されていますか？
>   ・キーストアの設定は正しいですか？
>   設定を修正した後、再度ビルドを実行してください。

なお、細かいエラーとして、以下の内容が出力されました。

> Temporary folder: /private/tmp/monaca/5786691bfd1734a978677336
>   Downloading project
>   Download complete
>   Running for 5.2
>   plugin add mobi.monaca.plugins.Monaca
>   No ALTQ support in kernel
>   ALTQ related functions disabled
>   pfctl: pf already enabled
>   Fetching plugin "mobi.monaca.plugins.Monaca" via npm
>   Installing "mobi.monaca.plugins.Monaca" for android
>   No ALTQ support in kernel
>   ALTQ related functions disabled
>   pf disabled
>   plugin add mobi.monaca.plugins.WebIntent
>   No ALTQ support in kernel
>   ALTQ related functions disabled
>   pf enabled
>   Fetching plugin "mobi.monaca.plugins.WebIntent" via npm
>   Installing "mobi.monaca.plugins.WebIntent" for android
>   No ALTQ support in kernel
>   ALTQ related functions disabled
>   pf disabled
>   plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.0.0
>   No ALTQ support in kernel
>   ALTQ related functions disabled
>   pf enabled
>   Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.0.0" via npm
>   Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for android
>   No ALTQ support in kernel
>   ALTQ related functions disabled
>   pf disabled
>   plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen@2.1.0
>   No ALTQ support in kernel
>   ALTQ related functions disabled
>   pf enabled
>   Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-splashscreen@2.1.0" via npm
>   Installing "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" for android
>   No ALTQ support in kernel
>   ALTQ related functions disabled
>   pf disabled
>   plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation@1.0.1
>   No ALTQ support in kernel
>   ALTQ related functions disabled
>   pf enabled
>   Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-geolocation@1.0.1" via npm
>   Installing "cordova-plugin-geolocation" for android
>   No ALTQ support in kernel
>   ALTQ related functions disabled
>   pf disabled
>   plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview@1.3.1 --variable XWALK_VERSION=14.43.343.25 
>   No ALTQ support in kernel
>   ALTQ related functions disabled
>   pf enabled
>   Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview@1.3.1" via npm
>   Installing "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" for android
>   No ALTQ support in kernel
>   ALTQ related functions disabled
>   pf disabled
>   plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs@1.1.1
>   No ALTQ support in kernel
>   ALTQ related functions disabled
>   pf enabled
>   Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-dialogs@1.1.1" via npm
>   Installing "cordova-plugin-dialogs" for android
>   No ALTQ support in kernel
>   ALTQ related functions disabled
>   pf disabled
>   Project has 7 plugins.
>   7 plugins has been installed.
>   No ALTQ support in kernel
>   ALTQ related functions disabled
>   pf enabled
>   Running command: /private/tmp/monaca/5786691bfd1734a978677336/android/skeleton/hooks/after_prepare/monaca_enterprise_android.js /private/tmp/monaca/5786691bfd1734a978677336/android/skeleton
>   No ALTQ support in kernel
>   ALTQ related functions disabled
>   pf disabled
>   No ALTQ support in kernel
>   ALTQ related functions disabled
>   pf enabled
>   Running command: /private/tmp/monaca/5786691bfd1734a978677336/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/build --release
>   ANDROID_HOME=/Applications/android-sdk-macosx
>   JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home
>   Running: /private/tmp/monaca/5786691bfd1734a978677336/android/skeleton/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildRelease -b /private/tmp/monaca/5786691bfd1734a978677336/android/skeleton/platforms/android/build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
>   embedded
>   WARNING [Project: :] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
>   WARNING [Project: :] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
>   WARNING [Project: :] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
>   WARNING [Project: :] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
>   org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:14.43.343.25
>   :preBuild
>   :preArmv7ReleaseBuild
>   :checkArmv7ReleaseManifest
>   :preX86ReleaseBuild
>   :CordovaLib:compileLint
>   :CordovaLib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles
>   :CordovaLib:preBuild
>   :CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild
>   :CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest
>   :CordovaLib:prepareReleaseDependencies
>   :CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl
>   :CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript
>   :CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
>   :CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets
>   :CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues
>   :CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources
>   :CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources
>   :CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest
>   :CordovaLib:processReleaseResources
>   :CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources
>   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   :CordovaLib:compileReleaseJava
>   :CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:packageReleaseJar
>   :CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk
>   :CordovaLib:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:bundleRelease
>   :prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedReleaseLibrary
>   :preArmv7DebugBuild
>   :preX86DebugBuild
>   :CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles
>   :CordovaLib:preDebugBuild
>   :CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
>   :CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
>   :CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl
>   :CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
>   :CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   :CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets
>   :CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues
>   :CordovaLib:generateDebugResources
>   :CordovaLib:packageDebugResources
>   :CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
>   :CordovaLib:processDebugResources
>   :CordovaLib:generateDebugSources
>   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   :CordovaLib:compileDebugJava
>   :CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:packageDebugJar
>   :CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk
>   :CordovaLib:packageDebugJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:packageDebugLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:bundleDebug
>   :prepareOrgXwalkXwalk_core_library144334325Library
>   :prepareArmv7ReleaseDependencies
>   :compileArmv7ReleaseAidl
>   :compileArmv7ReleaseRenderscript
>   :generateArmv7ReleaseBuildConfig
>   :generateArmv7ReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :mergeArmv7ReleaseAssets
>   :createXwalkCommandLineFileArmv7Release
>   :generateArmv7ReleaseResValues
>   :generateArmv7ReleaseResources
>   :mergeArmv7ReleaseResources
>   :processArmv7ReleaseManifest
>   :processArmv7ReleaseResources
>   :generateArmv7ReleaseSources
>   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   :compileArmv7ReleaseJava
>   :lintVitalArmv7Release
>   :compileArmv7ReleaseNdk
>   :preDexArmv7Release
>   :dexArmv7Release
>   :processArmv7ReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>   :validateReleaseSigning
>   :packageArmv7Release FAILED
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':packageArmv7Release'.
>   > Failed to read key hollywoodmap from store "/private/tmp/monaca/5786691bfd1734a978677336/android/skeleton/etc/keystore.private": Cannot recover key
>   * Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>   BUILD FAILED
>   Total time: 15.67 secs
>   /private/tmp/monaca/5786691bfd1734a978677336/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
>                       throw e;
>                             ^
>   Error code 1 for command: /private/tmp/monaca/5786691bfd1734a978677336/android/skeleton/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildRelease,-b,/private/tmp/monaca/5786691bfd1734a978677336/android/skeleton/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
>   ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /private/tmp/monaca/5786691bfd1734a978677336/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
>   You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
>   Error: /private/tmp/monaca/5786691bfd1734a978677336/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (/data/monaca_build_module/5.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
>       at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:822:5)
>   Build error: Error building project source code

Comment: 面倒かもしれませんが、新規プロジェクトを作成し、ファイルやプラグイン、コンポーネントの追加、アプリ設定などを行った方が早いかもしれません。

Comment: 確かに、これは解決手段になるかも知れませんね。最悪の場合、新規プロジェクトからの設定し直しも検討したいと思います！

Answer (score 1):

バージョンアップにより
今のプロジェクトのプラグインなどの設定と`gradle`の設定があっていないような気がするので、
コメントでoTakさんの言うとおり新規プロジェクトをベースにソースやプラグインを移行してみて、
それでも駄目なら、ビルド環境の問題なので`monaca`に問い合わせするといいかと思います。

Answer (score 0):

デバッグビルドは成功しますか？

エラーログを見ると、キーストアのリカバリーに失敗しているようなので、キーストアを上書きしてしまったか、あるいは、キーストアのパスワードが間違っているのではないかと思います。

Comment: キーストアを入れなおしましたが、やはりエラーが出てしまいました。となると控えているパスワードが異なるのか、もっと別の理由かですね……。

Comment: デバッグビルドであれば成功しますか？　また、ビルド時のエラーは今回のようにCannot recover keyというメッセージを含んでいますか？

Answer (score 0):

私も同じようになったことがあったときは
キーストアを一旦ほかのものに設定してビルドしてみると
ビルドに成功しました

そのあと正しいキーストアに設定してビルドするという対応をして解決しました
参考になれば幸いです

Answer (score -1):

当方も、本日同様の事象が起こりました。（最後にビルド成功していたのは2016年6末でした）

試行錯誤の末、パッケージ名に含まれるアンダースコアを除去したらビルドが通るようになりました。

Androidは従来アンダースコアはOKでしたが、AndroidもしくはMonacaの仕様変更が入った可能性を疑っています。

もし、パッケージ名にアンダースコアが含まれている状況でしたら、一度お試し願います。

Comment: これ以降、アンダースコアを含めてもビルドが通るようになりました。